# Boot setup option is being skipped, Windows launches right away

Tags: windows, boot

I'm trying to boot from a USB disk.

When I restart my computer though, it skips the option of pressing F12 to choose boot device, and immediately launches Windows.

How do I stop this happening?

Comment: What OS? What make and model of computer? Have you entered the BIOS before? Are you sure the key to press is F12?

Comment: Should try enter BIOS and set 1st booting decice to USB drive (some mainboards, the external flash drive doesn't show in USB harddisk list, but in Harddisk>>'List of both fixed hardrive and removable drives').

Most mainboard also has got a setting to allow user display full startup process without skipping anything (OEM logo, statics, etc...)

Comment: Is this on windows 8? I'm guessing its an OEM machine and you have fastboot turned on. Could you confirm the OS and what make/model system this is?

Comment: It's Windows 7, on a Toshiba Satalite with a clean Windows install. 

It usually does show the boot option. I appear to have resolved by constantly pressing F12 as I restarted it.